# IReport: Crosstab: adding row group

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, crosstab

I have this Jasper Report that have a Crosstab placed on the Summary band. Though the Crosstab's dataset is based from the Query of the file, I need to add a third row group to it.

The question is how? I may have sucessfully added the third row by clicking `Add Row Group` on the Row Groups of the Crosstab. When compiling / previewing the report, it prompts an error `Crosstab bucket expression missing for group <field>`. This may be caused missing attributes in  the other bands of related to  in the Crosstab. I've tried to supply some `static text` or other components but it returns that the placement is invalid.

How can I add another row group to the crosstab knowing that a Crosstab by default can only only two row groups allowed upon its creation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have added a valid expression in the Bucket expression property for this row group.  From the error message it sounds like it may have been left blank.  It should be whatever field or expression you want to group on.

If you have filled it in, make sure that it is valid for the datasource for the cross tab.